# Usage of Subquery very slow

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following query which works but takes about 1:20 min to finish:

```
user_total_revenue = (
    User.objects.annotate(
        total_revenue=Sum("payments__amount"),
        first_order_date=Subquery(
            User.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef("pk"))
            .annotate(first_order_date=Min("shops__orders__created"))
            .values("first_order_date"),
            output_field=DateTimeField(),
        ),
    )
)
```

Raw SQL Query:

```sql
SELECT
   "users_user"."id",
   "users_user"."created",
   "users_user"."updated",
   "users_user"."user_id",
   "users_user"."name",
   "users_user"."address",
   SUM("payments_payment"."amount") AS "total_revenue",
   (
      SELECT
         MIN(U2."created") AS "first_order_date" 
      FROM
         "users_user" U0 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "shops_shop" U1 
            ON (U0."id" = U1."user_id") 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "orders_order" U2 
            ON (U1."id" = U2."shop_id") 
      WHERE
         U0."id" = 
         (
            "users_user"."id"
         )
      GROUP BY
         U0."id"
   )
   AS "first_order_date" 
FROM
   "users_user" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "payments_payment" 
      ON ("users_user"."id" = "payments_payment"."user_id") 
GROUP BY
   "users_user"."id",
   (
      SELECT
         MIN(U2."created") AS "first_order_date" 
      FROM
         "users_user" U0 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "shops_shop" U1 
            ON (U0."id" = U1."user_id") 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "orders_order" U2 
            ON (U1."id" = U2."shop_id") 
      WHERE
         U0."id" = 
         (
            "users_user"."id"
         )
      GROUP BY
         U0."id"
   )
   LIMIT 21
```

Because it was so slow I wrote it in a different way which is much faster (< 1 second):

```
def user_total_revenue():
    first_orders = (
        User.objects.annotate(first_order_date=Min("shops__orders__created"))
        .values("pk", "first_order_date")
    )
    first_orders = {
        item["pk"]: item["first_order_date"] for item in first_orders
    }

    user_total_revenue = User.objects.annotate(total_revenue=Sum("payments__amount"))

    return [
        {
            "user": user,
            "first_order_date": first_orders[user.pk],
        }
        for user in user_total_revenue
    ]
```

I would like to understand why my first version is so slow using the Subquery.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show  the SQL that is produced?

Comment: use Django-debug-toolbar or a chrome extension to figure out what's going on. My guess is that `User.objects.filter(pk=...` is duplicated multiple times what makes the query slow.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% here but I believe the query produced by this should be faster.

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
from django.db.models import Value

user_total_revenue = User.objects.annotate(
    total_revenue=Coalesce(
        Subquery(
            Payment.object.filter(user_id=OuterRef("pk"))
            .values("user_id")
            .annotate(sum=Sum("amount"))
            .values("sum")[:1]
        ),
        Value(0),
    ),
    first_order_date=Subquery(
        User.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef("pk"))
        .annotate(first_order_date=Min("shops__orders__created"))
        .values("first_order_date"),
        output_field=DateTimeField(),
    ),
)
```

Other things to try:

- Using `order_by("shops__orders__created")` and picking first item instead of the `Min`
- Adding an index for `created` on order